# DataGridView Standard context menu

Tags: c#, datagridview, contextmenu

I have a `DataGridView`, and I need to disable the standard context menu (right click) when I'm editing a cell. Also I have my own context menu (on right click too), but it should work when I don't edit it.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.
you can modify this to show your context menu and disable the default context menu.

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Control.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    }
```